# How can I display something if its opened with Oulook and if its not display something else?

Tags: html, outlook

So basicly I made a html email that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<!--[if mso ]>
<body>
<p>Hello world, its Outlook!</p>
</body>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso ]>
<body>
<p>Hello world, its NOT Outlook!</p>
</body>
<![endif]-->
</html>
```

Now here is the problem, when I open the mail with Outlook correct body tag with its children is rendered which is correct "Hello world, its outlook!".

But when I open the mail with Gmail or Hotmail its blank nothing is displayed..

Whats the problem? And how can I make sure that the "NOT Outlook" body tag and its children is displayed if its not outlook and if it is Outlook how can I display the first top body tag with its children in same html markup?

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer:

```
<!--[if mso ]>
...
<![endif]-->

<![if !mso ]>
...
<![endif]>
```